# How to change the height and width of the master page in BIRT?

Tags: birt

Here's what I'm trying to do : I have to change the height and width of the master page dynamically based up on the parameter which i send through the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in the beforeFactory event. Firstly it is necessary to fill the "name" property of the master page as described in [this topic](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200688/).

Saying we have an integer "myHeight" report parameter:

```
var dynamicHeight=params["myHeight"].value+"in"; //don't forget the unit
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findMasterPage("myMasterPage").setProperty("height", 
dynamicHeight);
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findMasterPage("myMasterPage").pageType="custom";
```